# How to return predictions in the [0, 1] interval for SVMs in vowpal wabbit

Tags: vowpalwabbit

Apologies if this has been asked already. Instead of the raw predictions (`-r`) I would like to return predictions in the [0, 1] interval for an SVM trained in vowpal wabbit by setting `-loss_function hinge`. Currently I'm trying this but it's not giving me what I want. Any thoughts?

```
vw -d vw_train_rand.vw -c -f svm_rand.vw --passes 10 --loss_function hinge -q cn;

vw -d vw_test_rand.vw -t -i svm_rand.vw -p preds_rand_svm.txt
```

Cheers

Aaron

EDIT:

1) Sample data:

```
-1 |c Loan.TypeConventional:1 Loan.TypeFHA:0 Loan.TypeUnknown:0 Loan.TypeVA:0 |n Loan.Size:124500 LenderRank0612.0614:1939 ZipSquareMiles:53.1 MailDateMonth:5 ZipPerForeignBorn:11.4 ZipPerHighSchoolPlusDegree:57.2 ZipPerCollegePlusDegree:15.2 ZipPerVeterans:13.4 ZipPopPerSquareMile:798.1 ZipPerUnemployement:8.5 ZipSexRatio:96.7 ZipHousingUnitsPerSquareMile:315.1 ZipMedianHouseholdIncome:36238 ZipPerCapitaIncome:19085 MonthsDeedDatetoMailDate:2
-1 |c Loan.TypeConventional:1 Loan.TypeFHA:0 Loan.TypeUnknown:0 Loan.TypeVA:0 |n Loan.Size:232000 LenderRank0612.0614:391 ZipSquareMiles:99.1 MailDateMonth:5 ZipPerForeignBorn:11.8 ZipPerHighSchoolPlusDegree:73.3 ZipPerCollegePlusDegree:39.3 ZipPerVeterans:9.1 ZipPopPerSquareMile:485.5 ZipPerUnemployement:5.9 ZipSexRatio:98.5 ZipHousingUnitsPerSquareMile:169.6 ZipMedianHouseholdIncome:78465 ZipPerCapitaIncome:31908 MonthsDeedDatetoMailDate:3
-1 |c Loan.TypeConventional:1 Loan.TypeFHA:0 Loan.TypeUnknown:0 Loan.TypeVA:0 |n Loan.Size:90000 LenderRank0612.0614:130 ZipSquareMiles:32.6 MailDateMonth:5 ZipPerForeignBorn:51.5 ZipPerHighSchoolPlusDegree:60.7 ZipPerCollegePlusDegree:17.3 ZipPerVeterans:9.3 ZipPopPerSquareMile:783.2 ZipPerUnemployement:4.8 ZipSexRatio:97.2 ZipHousingUnitsPerSquareMile:274.2 ZipMedianHouseholdIncome:64668 ZipPerCapitaIncome:25632 MonthsDeedDatetoMailDate:3
-1 |c Loan.TypeConventional:0 Loan.TypeFHA:0 Loan.TypeUnknown:0 Loan.TypeVA:1 |n Loan.Size:121301 LenderRank0612.0614:23 ZipSquareMiles:6.8 MailDateMonth:5 ZipPerForeignBorn:14.9 ZipPerHighSchoolPlusDegree:63.9 ZipPerCollegePlusDegree:24.2 ZipPerVeterans:10 ZipPopPerSquareMile:5245.1 ZipPerUnemployement:7.1 ZipSexRatio:93.3 ZipHousingUnitsPerSquareMile:2001.6 ZipMedianHouseholdIncome:56398 ZipPerCapitaIncome:25815 MonthsDeedDatetoMailDate:2
```

2) What I get currently:

```
-1.001968
-1.000737
-1.000441
-1.001823
```

3) What I'd like to see: Predictions in a continuous [0, 1] interval such that each entry can be interpreted as a forecasted probability associated with the event, e.g.:

```
0.012
0.009
0.010
0.0085
```

Comment: Aaron, can you please add the following to the question: 1) a few lines of the data-set, both train and test 2) what you expect? vs. 3) what you get?

Comment: Hi @arielf, see edits above.

Comment: To convert raw predicts to logistic probabilities you may always pipe results through the external `utl/logistic` utility.  Results will be signed (direction + probability within direction).  The `vw` option `--link logistic` may also work for some option combinations.  Also see Martin's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to predict probabilities, you should train with `--loss_function=logistic` and test with `--link=logistic`. The hinge loss (used in SVM) results in max-margin classifier, which is not suitable for predicting probabilities.

Note that just using `--loss_function=hinge` does not make SVM from VW (there is no kernel). If you want Support Vector Machine with radial-basis kernel trained in online fashion, use `--kvsm --kernel=rbf` (see `vw --ksvm -h | grep -A9 KSVM` for more parameters).

Comment: very helpful, thank you. is there an exhaustive list somewhere, laid out in a relatively clear fashion, that documents all the ML frameworks implemented in vowpal wabbit? the GitHub documentation, for example, didn't have anything in it that I saw about neural networks or radial basis kernels. It's a great tool. Thanks for supporting it!

Comment: There is no exhaustive documentation. Some VW parameters are described [at the wiki](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-line-arguments), but VW is quickly developing, so the wiki becomes outdated. Contributions are welcome (anyone can edit the wiki). Some documentation is also linked from [the tutorial](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Tutorial). For example, [the ksvm documentation](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/ksvm.pdf) says that `--reprocess` is an important parameter.

Comment: The [examples in tests](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/test/RunTests#L1063) may be also very helpful when trying to find out how to use a new (undocumented) reduction. `vw -h` should print a list of all reductions. If you want to know all parameters of a given reduction (e.g. `--ksvm` or `--nn`), you must add the reduction parameter to the command (e.g. `vw -h --ksvm` or `vw -h --nn 1`).

Comment: Thanks for sharing `vw --ksvm -h | grep -A9 KSVM`.  That's a useful trick!

Comment: Hi there, how would I adapt a cost sensitive classifier for this? It recommends not changing `loss_function` for multi-class classification. https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/issues/1082 for context.

Comment: For `--oaa` and `--csoaa_ldf=mc`, there is an option `--probabilities` (so `--link=logisitic` is not needed, but you still must use `--loss_function=logistic`).