# How to convert Vowpal Wabbit logistic predictions to probabilities

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I have given vowpal wabbit a dataset with two labels and performed logistic regression with it. The problem is, it is returning real numbers varying from positive to negative as prediction. Now if I want to transform these values to probability of some sort. How should I go about it.

I was thinking maybe the predicted value is a'x where a is coefficient vector and x is the feature vector. If this is the case then I can directly use the binomial link function to get the probs.

Answer (score 3):

Use `--link=logistic` in command line.
Alternatively you may use script `logistic` in vw's `utl` folder to convert already obtained results.
Pls refer to [How to return predictions in the [0, 1] interval for SVMs in vowpal wabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30797081/841424)

Comment: I used the command line `vw --save_resume --readable_model ob/e/nsefut/VW_testing/buyModel.VWM -d ob/e/nsefut/VW_testing/VWbuy.VWF --quiet --predictions ob/e/nsefut/VW_testing/buyPredict.VWP --loss_function logistic --noconstant -f ob/e/nsefut/VW_testing/vwBuyModel.m --link logistic` . Then it says --link unrecognised option.

Comment: Mine works fine. Could you try `--link=logistic` instead of `--link logistic`? Probably your VW version is too old. What's your VW version? You can get v8.0 from github